# Scikit alternative for categorical data modeling?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, categorical-data

So, `sklearn` doesn't support categorical data in its models. Is there a known alternative for categorical data modeling (such as random forests, etc.) for Python?

Comment: Why not processing / encoding your categorical features ?

Comment: Are you suggesting one-hot? It seems like a too much of a workaround just because the library doesn't support it

Comment: Sklearn provides features processing tools including one Hot encoding. See http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.preprocessing

Comment: Still, seems like a workaround simply because this specific library doesn't support it. Is there nothing else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are definitely ways to process your data to make categorical data compatible with sklearn (e.g one-hot encoding). An alternative you can look into is h2o, which supports categorical features natively (although it doesn't offer the breadth of models of sklearn).

Answer (score 1):

[statsmodel](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/example_formulas.html#categorical-variables) supports Fitting models using R-style formulas:

```py
In [5]: df = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("Guerry", "HistData").data

In [6]: df = df[['Lottery', 'Literacy', 'Wealth', 'Region']].dropna()

In [7]: df.head()
Out[7]: 
   Lottery  Literacy  Wealth Region
0       41        37      73      E
1       38        51      22      N
2       66        13      61      C
3       80        46      76      E
4       79        69      83      E
```

You can fit models without processing categorical data

```
In [11]: res = smf.ols(formula='Lottery ~ Literacy + Wealth + C(Region)', data=df).fit()

In [12]: print(res.params)
Intercept         38.651655
C(Region)[T.E]   -15.427785
C(Region)[T.N]   -10.016961
C(Region)[T.S]    -4.548257
C(Region)[T.W]   -10.091276
Literacy          -0.185819
Wealth             0.451475
dtype: float64
```